# How to update exact decimal value in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

I am working with mysql. I created a column in database called "balance" and the datatype for this column is "DECIMAL(12,6)".

So whenever I try to update 4 digits after the decimal point then the last two digits are showing random values (e.g. balance is showing 4444.888672 for the following query).

Here is my current query

```
UPDATE `table` SET `balance` = '4444.8888' WHERE `token_address` = 'abc123'
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/_8e_V3jG

Comment: It sounds like `balance` is actually `FLOAT`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like common float overflow issue, where decimal part does not fit into memory and is cut off.

In our system we use INT's instead. So you would save into database `44448888000` and in PHP you would parse it as `$row['balance'] / 1000000`

Comment: can i save with decimal if yes then how ? means how can i fix this ?

Comment: @RajniDhiman Where it's showing like that? In database itself or in back-end (php?)

Comment: In Database (phpmyadmin)